# Put as many elements as possible in each page print

Tags: html, css

I am trying to print categories, each category contains unknown number of elements.

Every page needs:

1. Header and footer.
2. To include categories as much as possible

I try to do "position:fixed" for the header and footer, and "page-break-inside: avoid" for the category container. first page look fine, but in the others the categories start from top of the page, and behind the header.

The question is :

1. There is a way to do that in media print?
2. If not, there is any way to render the page that looks like what i wont, and just print it?

this is the example:

```html
<style>
  @media print {
    .category {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .page {
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
  }
</style>


<body>
  <h1 style="position:fixed">this text hide the category in second page </h1>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="category">
      Category 1<br/>item<br/>item<br/>item<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      Category 2<br/>item<br/>item<br/>item<br/>item<br/>item<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="category">
      Category 3<br/>item<br/>item
    </div>

    <!--and so on  -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add top and bottom padding to your page containers, according to the height of your header/footer.

Comment: Padding top work only in the first page...

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's difficult to help.

Comment: I added code example.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i do it with calculate the div height each category, and add page-break always if needed.

```
for (let cat of menu.categories) {
      mywindow.document.write('<div id="' + cat._id + '" class="content">');
      // Write category
      mywindow.document.write('</div>');  //end of content
  var currentPageDivHeight = mywindow.document.getElementById('A4').clientHeight - (1000 * pageNamber);
    console.log('currentPageDivHeight:' + currentPageDivHeight)
  if ( currentPageDivHeight > 750) {
    pageNamber++;
    mywindow.document.getElementById(cat._id).style.setProperty("page-break-before",  'always');
    mywindow.document.getElementById(cat._id).style.setProperty("padding-top",  '5cm');
  }
}
```